# Given $\langle f,g \rangle := \frac12\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(x)\overline{g(x)}\,dx$ I'm searching an example of $f \neq 0$ such that $\langle f,f\rangle=0$

Tags: linear-algebra, fourier-series, examples-counterexamples, inner-products

Given the inner product

$$\langle f,g \rangle := \frac12 \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(x)\overline{g(x)}\,dx$$

I'm searching an example of $f \neq 0$ such that $\langle f,f\rangle=0$.

Comment: If you were to find such an $f$, then this object can't be an inner product. Positive definiteness is an axiomatic conditon for inner products.

Comment: To make explicit, this works because the phrase "given the inner product" already implies that we are agreeing to associate functions which disagree only on null sets together.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is impossible for one of two reasons. Either

$(1)$ We take it on linear algebra faith that the object is a well defined inner product, so such an $f$ cannot exist because it violates positive definiteness or

$(2)$ We prove it with calculus.

$$\langle f, f \rangle = \frac{1}{2}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} |f(x)|^2dx$$

The integrand is strictly nonnegative. Thus the only way the integral evaluates to $0$ is if the integrand is $0$:

$$|f(x)|^2 = 0 \: \text{a.e.} \implies f(x) = 0 \: \text{a.e.}$$

Comment: no one said the function has to be continuous right? so maybe just take $f$ to be $1$ at a single point and $0$ everywhere else

Comment: Yes that's right. The function does not has to be continuous. I think this is a good idea, thank you.

Comment: @MatijaSreckovic we do implicitly demand the functions be in equivalence classes because we called this an inner product on a vector space. If that requirement is gone and this is just some interval everything is fine, but then we cannot call this an inner product.

Answer (score 0):

Since nothing is said in the question that $f$ must be continuous or that we are considering functions module null sets, then there are examples. Here's one:
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases}
0 & (x \neq 0) \\
1 & (x = 0)
\end{cases}
$$

Answer (score 0):

If you are not limiting the domain of $f$, you can take 
$$
f(x)=\begin{cases}
|x|-\pi,&\ |x|\geq\pi, \\ \ \\
0,&\ -\pi<x<\pi
\end{cases}
$$
Then $f$ is continuous and $$\int_{-\pi}^\pi |f(x)|^2\,dx=0.$$